# Javascript, DOM: Need to find the space inside a scrollable element

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, measurement

I have a scrollable element with a child.  Inside this child (which has no preset width or height) are a set of absolutely positioned elements that can have arbitrary width, height, left, and top values.  The parent element is able to scroll to accommodate viewing these absolutely positioned elements wherever they are, but I'm having trouble retrieving how much of this scrollable space is inside this parent.  How do I do this?

For reference, here's some of my CSS:

```
.ruler_container {
    max-width:  620px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow:   auto;
}

.ruler {
    position:   relative;
}

    .inner_elem {
        position:       absolute;
    }
```

The width, height, left, and top values for `inner_elem`s are arbitrary.

Comment: Adding your code would be helpful

Comment: If the inner elements are positioned absolutely, then this question really makes no sense. Some container element (like that "child" you mention) would have to be `position: relative` to "capture" the absolutely-positioned elements. However, absolutely positioned elements are out of the layout flow (by definition), so I don't see how you'll get any content boundary to wrap around them.

Comment: You mean there's no way to get the scrollable space inside the parent?

Comment: adding a simple HTML structure example would help you get an answer to your question. Also, you can get the height of an element if it is scrollable or not but having things positioned absolutely means that the absolutely positioned element parent doesn't take those elements into consideration for its height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my answer after digging through the DOM: The scrollWidth and scrollHeight attributes.

My code and DOM structure are quite complex now, so it was hard to make this question more accurate beyond the above details.